# Text in Video caption not seen on laptop

Tags: video

I use google pixel where I take daily videos, where then I click the three dots and on the video caption I write some text about the video, describing it or adding some information that is important to me. I do this as a part of a project.

I thought that once I download these videos to my laptop, I would just go to properties and then on the metadata I would see the caption I have written. However, this seems to not be the case as I do not see any of the text I have written.

Comment: So, what is the question?  (1) How to save it because its not there? (2) Or how to retrieve it when its there?

Comment: Welcome to Android.SE. Just to make sure, is this about captions/text descriptions in Google Photos?

Answer (score 1):

According to an [old Google Sites post](https://sites.google.com/site/picasaresources/google-photos-1/how-to-add-and-view-captions) discussing the nature of the relationship of Google Photos to Picasa, it appears that Descriptions are not preserved when downloading a photo or video:

> Captions added after uploading to Google Photos are NOT written to the metadata of the photo. The captions will be lost when you download from Google Photos. A way to preserve the captions was to download using File > Import from Google Photos in Picasa3 on the computer, but Google disabled that option in 2018. The only way left is by using Google Takeout but you need special software and skills.

The referenced Google Takeout method is described [here](https://sites.google.com/site/picasaresources/google-photos-1/how-to-download-all-autobackupped-pictures?authuser=0):

> In Google Photos, "Captions" added before uploading are now shown as "Other" in the info of a photo. They always remain part of the photo.
>
> "Descriptions" added in Google Photos are lost when downloading from Google Photos, but transferred by other methods (Partner sharing, sharing albums).

This seems to refer to uploading to Google Photos from the device, as the "Description" pen doesn't appear in the Pixel photo viewer until *after* the photo has been uploaded. I've tried myself to add a caption prior to uploading by disabling all data, recording a video and adding a caption, then reenabling data. The Description/caption still appears in Google Photos, but is not available as part of the file once downloaded. It does appear there are more intensive methods of accomplishing this task, although it may require [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com) and an EXIF editor.

> When using Google Takeout, a .json file in the downloaded ZIP file includes info about the added description, location, and changed date. There are tools able to merge .json and image:
>
> **EXIFTool**
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42024255/bulk-join-json-with-jpg-from-google-takeout
> To add a description of the file, the appropriate placement for this would be IPTC:Caption-Abstract, XMP:Description, and EXIF:ImageDescription. You could copy these with:
> '-Caption-Abstract<Description', -Description, or '-ImageDescription<Description'
> https://github.com/mattwilson1024/google-photos-exif  (2020)
> [How to merge image with his .json file (Google Photos takeout)](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=11064.0)  - Exiftool forum
>
> **MetadataFixer** can fix EXIF Metadata in pictures and videos when exporting from Google Takeout. There is a demo version and a paid version: https://metadatafixer.com/.
>
> [How to batch merge Google Takeout photos with json files on Mac](https://www.fireebok.com/resource/how-to-batch-merge-google-takeout-photos-with-json-files-on-mac.html)